# How to adapt output with multiple columns for better presentation?

Tags: r

Recently I've started using RMarkdown in RStudio, and I don't know how to adapt the output for a useful presentation. The variables in the data set being: `Cia`, `Riesgo`, `Tipo.Refa`, `Estado.Poliza`, `Tipo.Endoso`, `Asegurado`, `Moneda`, `Suma.Asegurada`, `Prima.Pesos`, `Premio.Pesos`, `Puntos`, and `Pesos`.
The only thing I want is find a way to present the data in a more understandable format, unlike the images I attached. (dimensions of the R object are 9 rows, 12 variables)

A bit of help would be much appreciated.

````
```{r setup, echo = FALSE}
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = '/Users/Igna43/Dropbox/Nacho/Nacho 2016/Análisis R')
```


```{r echo = FALSE}
data1<-read.csv(file = "ListadoEnero2016.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
opneg1<-subset(data1, data1$Pesos. < 0, )
opneg1
```
````

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `kable()` (see [manual](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/knitr/versions/1.15.1/topics/kable) to create tables that are directly in markdown format.

Your code would become:

````
```{r,results='asis'}
 knitr::kable(opneg1)
```
````

See also [this great manual on rmarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_rcodechunks.html).